# Unable to show keyboard when returning to the same activity - PinEntryEditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I followed this example (https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/building-a-pinentryedittext-in-android-5f2eddcae5d3) to create a PinEntryEditText in my app. What I want, is to display the keyboard every single time I open the activity containing the PinEntryEditText. I'm doing this by requesting focus in the `onResume` method.

The problem is that the keyboard **doesn't appear** when opening a new activity and **returning** back to the activity containing the PinEntryEditText.

What could be the issue here?

```
    override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    pinEntry_editText.post { pinEntry_editText.requestFocus() }
}
```

This is what I've tried:

- setting focusable/focusableInTouchMode in XML
- setting focusable/focusableInTouchMode in the `onResume` method
- created a function inside the `PinEntryEditText` containing `requestFocus`/`focusable`/`focusableInTouchMode` and called it in the `onResume` method
- calling this function in the `onResume` method:

  ```
   fun AppCompatEditText.requestKeyboardFocus() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
  ```

  }

In `AndroidManifest` I added this line to my activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest listening for current focus changes and force show the keyboard.
first add a showSoftKeyboard fun:

```
private fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
        
        // here is one more tricky issue
        // imm.showSoftInputMethod doesn't work well
        // and imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0) doesn't work well for all cases too
        imm?.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)
    }
}
```

Update your onResume fun:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    currentFocus?.let {
        showSoftKeyboard(it)
    }
    pinEntry_editText.requestFocus()
}
```

**

```
pinEntry_editText.post { // Do work on UI Thread }
```

This is useful when we are not on UI thread and we want to switch back to make some UI change, so there is no need for that in this case since onResume will be called on the UI thread.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Nice approach! Thanks! ^_^

Comment: Awesome! Glad I was of help!